$f_n \rightarrow f$ p.w. $\Rightarrow$ $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$
Given $(X_n)$ a sequence of random variables with associated probability density functions a sequence of random variables with associated probability density functions $(f_n)$, which converge pointwise to a probability density function $f$ of a random variable $X$. Show that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$.
Solution / Proof:
Let $x$ be a continuity point of $F$ (CDF of $X$).
Then:
$$
|F_{X_n}(x) - F(x)| = \left| \int_{-\infty}^x f_n(t) dt - \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt \right|
$$
$$
= \left| \int_{-\infty}^x (f_n(t) - f(t))dt \right|
$$
$$
\leq \int_{-\infty}^x |f_n(t) - f(t)|  dt
$$
$$
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} (f_n(t) - f(t)) dt + 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \max(f(t) - f_n(t), 0) dt
$$
The first summand is constant 0.
The second summand goes to 0 by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.
Questions:
I don't quite understand the last estimation where the integral over $(-\infty, x]$ is replaced by the integral over $\mathbb{R}$. Specifically, why does it change to $\mathbb{R}$ and why do we involve the $\max$ function?
Additionally, the final part states that the second summand goes to 0 by the Dominated Convergence Theorem. Could someone explain this in more detail?
Any help to clarify these points would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

First question: Integral of a non-negative function over a subset of $\mathbb R$ is less than or equal to the integral over $\mathbb R$.
Second question:  For any real number $a$ we have $|a|=a+2\max \{-a,0\}$. [To see this  consider the cases $a \ge 0$ and $a<0$].
Third question: $0 \le \max \{f(t)-f_n(t),0\} \le f(t)$ and $f$ is integrable, so DCT can be applied.
